# Shogun toolbox error freeing memory when SGVector goes out of scope

Tags: c++, windows, shogun

I built [Shogun toolbox ML master](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun) on Windows 10 x64, VisualStudio 2019.
I run the classifier_minimal_svm sample; it works, but I get this error every time an `SGVector` goes out of scope

```
{
 SGVector<float64_t> y_values(100); 
}
```

there is this error:

```
Critical error detected c0000374
classifier_minimal_svm.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC395DB0B9 (ntdll.dll) in classifier_minimal_svm.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted 
(parameters: 0x00007FFC396427F0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC395DB0B9 (ntdll.dll) in classifier_minimal_svm.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FFC396427F0).

classifier_minimal_svm.exe!shogun::sg_free(void * ptr) Line 186 C++
classifier_minimal_svm.exe!shogun::sg_generic_free<double,0>(double * ptr) Line 124 C++
classifier_minimal_svm.exe!shogun::SGVector<double>::free_data() Line 405   C++
classifier_minimal_svm.exe!shogun::SGReferencedData::unref() Line 102   C++
classifier_minimal_svm.exe!shogun::SGVector<double>::~SGVector<double>() Line 173   C++
```

I edited a sample and have the error with just these lines of code:

```
#include <shogun/lib/SGVector.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    shogun::SGVector<float64_t> y_values1(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: heap corruption is typically caused elsewhere. Are you saying you get this by running the sample code?